# How do I create a menu separator bar in WPF using code

Tags: wpf, vb.net, menu

I am creating menus in WPF programatically using vb.net.  Can someone show me how I can add separator bar to a menu in code?  No xaml please.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

WPF has a [Separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.separator.aspx) control for just that purpose and it also separates your menu items when the appear on a toolbar. From the MSDN docs:

> A Separator control draws a line,
>   horizontal or vertical, between items
>   in controls, such as ListBox, Menu,
>   and ToolBar. Separator controls do not
>   react to any keyboard, mouse, mouse
>   wheel, or tablet input and cannot be
>   enabled or selected.

In code:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

//

Menu myMenu = new Menu();
myMenu.Items.Add(new Separator());
```

Answer (score 47):

In xaml:

```
<Menu>
   <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 1" />
   <Separator />
   <MenuItem Header="Menu Item 1" />
<Menu>
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question but this is exactly what I needed to see lol. I'm conflicted to give you a vote ><

Comment: Go on, take a risk. What have you got to loose! ;)

Comment: another vote, even though it is not the correct answer, it was just what i was looking for :)

Comment: Came here from google, was disappointed first because the question stated "in code". Luckily this answer was here as well. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

When using class System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem to build a menu, you can create a new empty MenuItem with a string of "-" to successfully add a separator line.

In code:

```
MenuItem restartAppMenu = new MenuItem("Restart", (sender, e) => {});
MenuItem closeMenu = new MenuItem("Quit", (sender, e) => {});
MenuItem SeparatorItem = new MenuItem("-");

MenuItem[] menuitems = new MenuItem[] { restartAppMenu,SeparatorItem, closeMenu };
tray.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(menuitems);
```